# Avoid a recursive stack overflow in promise-based loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, recursion, promise

As a simple example program, I have a node script which pings a server continuously, and wish for this program to be ran for a long time.

The program is set up as a ping function which returns a promise object. The promise is resolved or rejected based on whether the ping worked or failed.

I wish to have this function running in a loop, so regardless of whether the ping is successful or not, the next ping is then fired after a certain amount of time **after** the previous request has been resolved.

The problem is not this task itself, but I'm concerned about my implementation. I believe it will cause a stack overflow eventually.

Here's some code to see what's happening:

```
function doPing(host) {
    // returns a promise object.
}

function doEvery(ms, callback, callbackArgs) {

    setTimeout(function() {

        callback.apply(null, callbackArgs)
            .always(function() {

                doEvery(ms, callback, callbackArgs);

            });

    }, ms);

}

doEvery(1000, doPing, [host]);
```

I've tried to limit the code just to reflect the scope of the following questions:

Will this eventually cause a stack overflow?
Is there a pattern which prevents overflows for callback-based loops while using promises?

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate question - the one in question didn't appear in an initial search, or when writing up the question.
I believe this question is more specific. The question linked is opinion based while I've tried to keep this as objective and specific to promise-based loops as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No stack overflow here. `setTimeout` is an asynchronous function: it schedules the function to be run but does not invoke it immediately. Since the repeated call to `doEvery` is inside the callback for `setTimeout`, this will ensure that it does not overflow.

Here is an example of what the deepest stack might look like at various points:

- When scheduling the first ping: `[global scope] -> doEvery -> setTimeout`
- When running the first ping: `[event loop] -> [handle timer] -> [closure #1 in doEvery] -> callback.apply -> doPing`
- When the first response is received: `[event loop] -> [handle network] -> promise.resolve -> [closure #2 in doEvery] -> doEvery -> setTimeout`
- When the second timeout expires: `[event loop] -> [handle timer] -> [closure #1 in doEvery] -> callback.apply -> doPing`

So as you can see, every time you wait on a promise or a timeout, control is returned to the event loop. When the event (such as the timeout is reached or a ping response is received), the event loop then invokes the callback registered for that event.

Comment: Thanks. I was concerned that asynchronous functions would still cause a stack to grow.